# Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript

[This is with the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SDMm.png) Hey guys i have a problem with my javascript code. I try to do an animation when i click on a button, but i have this error :  Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
i don't know what's the problem !

```
import {
Util
```

} from './Util.js'

```
export class Introduction {

    /**
     * Classe permettant de créer et d'animer une introduction
     * @param {object} o - contient l'ensemble des mots d'intro
     * @param {DOMElement} elementParent - Conteneur de l'animation
     * @param {function} fonction - l'adresse de la fonction à exécuter après l'animation

     }}
     */

    constructor(o, elementParent, fonction) {
        //Récupérer les valeurs passées en paramètre            
        this.titrePrincipal = o.titrePrincipal;
        this.titreSecondaire = o.titreSecondaire
        this.titreTernaire = o.titreTernaire
        this.description = o.description
        this.elmParent = elementParent
        this.integrerIntro()
        this.fonction = fonction
    }


    integrerIntro() {
        /* Création des élément DOM qui seront animés. 
        Les éléments seront intégré dans le conteneur elmParent
        */
        console.log('introduction')
        let elmConteneur = this.creerElement(this.elmParent,
            'section',
            '',
            'introduction')

        let elmPrincipale = this.creerElement(elmConteneur,
            'div',
            this.titrePrincipal,
            'rectangle')

        let elmSecondaire = this.creerElement(elmConteneur,
            'div',
            this.titreSecondaire,
            'rectangle')


        let elmTernaire = this.creerElement(elmConteneur,
            'div',
            this.titreTernaire,
            'rectangle')

        let elmDescription = this.creerElement(elmConteneur,
            'div',
            this.description,
            'rectangle')

        let elmBouton = this.creerElement(elmConteneur,
            'button',
            'Commencer',
            'bouton')
        /* On garde une référence sur la fonction terminerIntro */
        let refTerminerIntro = this.terminerIntro.bind(this)
        elmBouton.addEventListener('mousedown', this.terminerIntro.bind(this))
    }

    creerElement(elmParent, balise, contenu, classCSS) {
        console.log(balise)
        let noeud = document.createElement(balise)
        if (contenu != '') {
            noeud.innerHTML = contenu
        }
        noeud.classList.add(classCSS)
        elmParent.appendChild(noeud)
        return noeud
    }

    terminerIntro(evt) {
        this.elmParent.firstChild.classList.add('deplacementContenuIntro')
        this.elmParent.firstChild.addEventListener('animationend', this.passerVersAnimationSuivante.bind(this))
    }

    passerVersAnimationSuivante(evt) {
        Util.detruireTousLesNoeud(this.elmParent, this.elmParent)
        this.fonction()
    }

}
```

i also have this file : i think a have a problem with my querySelector but i don't know :/

```
import {contenuIntro} from './contenuIntro.js' // le contenu de l'intoduction */
import {Introduction} from './Introduction.js' // 
import {AnimLettre} from './AnimLettre.js' //


/* l'élement de la page qui contiendra les éléments créés dynamiquement */
let elmHeader = document.querySelector('.header')
let intro = new Introduction(contenuIntro, elmHeader, animationLettre)
console.log(document.querySelector('.header'))

// debutQuestionnaire()

function animationLettre()
{
    /* Une fois que l'animation des mots est terminé la fonction animLettre s'exécutera */ 
    console.log('debut animation lettre')
    const lesLettres = 'Veille-technologique'
    let  monAnimLettre = new AnimLettre(lesLettres, elmHeader, finAnim) 
}


function finAnim()
{
    console.log('animation terminée')
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: can you show in what line the error is? In Util.js you have 4 adds

Comment: it's here : this.elmParent.firstChild.classList.add('deplacementContenuIntro')

Comment: Probably it is because elmParent is empty and it does not have a first child, Would you mind to make a console.log at it? Or to post your HTML with the button in a working snippet.

Comment: i can't put the snippet put here's my project : https://github.com/nejmahamadi/TP1_Veille

Comment: Ok I can see "Commencer" button is printing the error message, give me some time to debug it.

Comment: ok perfect thank u a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The first element of elmParent is not an HTML dom object, it does not have the `classList` property, that's why you are getting a `undefined` when calling `this.elmParent.firstChild.classList.add('deplacementContenuIntro')`

[image: screenshot]

Your element should have a `classList` property like the second and forth element of your node list

[image: screenshot2]

How to make sure it is a html element? just click on the object in the console and the inspector will select it in the web page

[image]

Even that this is not an actual answer-solution, it can explain the error and make a fix according to your logic. Nice struggling with French language though.

Comment: okay thank u a lot ! I'm gonna try to fix this and i'm from Montreal(Canada) that's why its in French !

Comment: Feels nice for helping a Canadian fellow. Maybe an upvote for the efforts :)?